# Update Attributes of Child Node XML DOM Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to figure out how to update multiple attributes of an XML node deep within an XML structure. I'm using Java with XML DOM class.  Consider the following XML structure:

```
<foo>
  <books>
    <book id="ABC" source="blah">
       <page id="01" language="english" value="fun"/>
       <page id="02" language="english" value="stuff"/>
       <page id="03" language="english" value="ant"/>
    </book>
    <book id="123" source="blah33">
       <page id="01" language="english" value="stuff"/>
       <page id="02" language="english" value="fun"/>
       <page id="03" language="english" value="yo"/>
    </book>
    .......
  </books>
</foo>
```

So I'm at page `Id 02` under Book `ABC` and I want to update value to a new set of text.  The problem is that I'm looping through a ***master*** book list and updating this separate XML DOM accordingly.  So at this point, I have a child Node object which does not have a way to set the attribute value.  It only have the `setNodeValue()` method available.

What am I missing here?  The XML structure in question is much bigger and a bit more complex but the example above illustrates the child relationship and where I need to update.

HELP!  Thanks in advance

```
.....
String masterColumnName = masterColumnNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
for (int j = 0; j < customerColumnList.getLength(); j++){
      Node customerColumnNode = customerColumnList.item(j);
      String customerColumnName = customerColumnNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();

      // Check for Match
      if (masterColumnName.equals(customerColumnName)){
          // Get Master & Customer Attributes
          NamedNodeMap masterColumnAttr = masterColumnNode.getAttributes();
          NamedNodeMap customerColumnAttr = customerColumnNode.getAttributes();

          customerColumnNode.<NO WAY TO DO> = masterColumnAttr.getNamedItem("function").getNodeValue();

......
```

Answer (score 0):

Well .... I figured it out. :) It's as simple as:

```
customerColumnAttr.getNamedItem("function").setTextContent(masterFunction);
```